# Javascript convert date

Tags: javascript, datetime

Using JavaScript, how do I find the local date from a string like:

2010-12-29T03:32:17-0800

I expect the result to be something like

2010-12-29T12:32:17

(GMT +0100)

Best regards,
Bob

Answer (score 0):

You could try [dateJs](http://www.datejs.com/), which will parse the string for you:

```
Date.parse("2010-12-29T03:32:17-0800")
```

Timezone information is taken into consideration and you will get a date object in local time. You can also easily add or subtract hours from a date object manually.

Answer (score 0):

You have date in the ISO 8601 format. To convert it to the `Date` you can use `setISO8601` method which code you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764459/why-will-this-dateparser-not-work-in-safari/3765216#3765216).